# Issue with Unity IAP RestorePurchases on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

My game has several levels, each unlocked (purchased) individually.

If you go to one (level X), open the IAP menu and purchase it, it becomes unlocked.
If you go to another one (level Y) and restore the purchases there, X and Y are unlocked.

How is this possible, considering the RestorePurchases just restores the exact ID of the level, which of course, is different for every level?

PS: I am using the standard unmodified restorePurhases script from here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

Answer (score 0):

1. If you go to level X, Purchase it and it became unlocked -> It's a right behaviour
2. RestorePurchases will restore all purchased products. so if you purchased X, then restore purchases, X and Y are unlocked -> It's a bug

Comment: "Becomes" not "remain", sorry, mistranslated. If you purchases one level, but then restoring, you unlock another level, that is not intentional. You pay for one level and you get all?

Comment: No, It will only restore purchased level